# How to show only numbers that are divisible by tick unit on javafx chart axis

Tags: java, javafx, charts, axis

Here's what I have now

[image]

As you can see, numbers on the left are not divisible by tick mark (in this situation by 50). I would like to see only numbers like 2950, 3000, 3050 etc. That includes top marker by the way (float up there is bothering me)

Answer (score 5):

If the auto ranging function does not provide the values you require for tick marks, you can configure the tick range manually.

```
yAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
yAxis.setLowerBound(1000);
yAxis.setUpperBound(5000);
yAxis.setTickUnit(500);
yAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);
```

*Sample Application*

Numbers on the Y Axis are only divisible by the tick unit (500) as specified for the axis.  Also the upper and lower bounds of the Y Axis are explicitly set, providing exact control over these values.

[image: sample app]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LineChartRanging extends Application {

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("Number of Month");
        final LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart =
                new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);

        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
        series.setName("My portfolio");
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 2317));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 1427));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 1573));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, 2452));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, 3495));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6, 3663));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(7, 2215));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(8, 4541));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 4393));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 1772));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(11, 2994));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(12, 2508));

        Scene scene  = new Scene(lineChart);
        lineChart.getData().add(series);
        lineChart.setPrefSize(500, 340);

        yAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
        yAxis.setLowerBound(1000);
        yAxis.setUpperBound(5000);
        yAxis.setTickUnit(500);
        yAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is, I already can dynamically change tickUnit. And I already do [that](https://gist.github.com/Meegooo/afc60e7a8ee7ed9a575e) and it works. I just call this method whenever I zoom (i have custom dedicated methods for that) or whenever height of the graph changes. But as you can see, it does not make axis use only those values which are divisible by `tickUnit`. Also, grid lines in JavaFX are terrible. Why do they have to jump all over the place and can't be static? When I [move graph](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/70032557/ShareX/2016/02/2016-02-05_01-45-03.mp4) it looks terrible

Comment: As far as I can tell, my answer answers the question as it was originally asked.  The original question does not refer to zooming and moving functionality and discussion of such items is outside the scope of topics I am prepared to answer here.

Comment: And it has nothing to do with zooming and moving. Those are just examples to better understand the problem (since you can visually see how grid stays on the same place and numbers on the left are changing). In question I asked how do I make axis show only values that are divisible by tick unit. I don't wanna see numbers like 2985, 3035, 3085 and especially 3396.57 with 2284.8. I wanna see only numbers like 2950, 3000, 3050 etc. If one tick was 100, those numbers would be 2900, 3000, 3100. If one tick was 250, those numbers would be 2750, 3000, 3250 etc.

Comment: About updated answer. Those are divisible by 500 only because lower and upper bounds are. And it looks like that's the only option. Which I can't do because then moving and zooming would be clunky. I was thinking about something like `yAxis.setStatic(true)`. I might look into `NumberAxis` or even just `Axis` to see if I can do something about that.

Comment: Hi @Meego , I am facing a similar issue --- on sliding the window I want to keep the original ticks which are divisible by 50 (or other value). Kindly update on how you solved it in the end. Thank you.

Comment: @Madrugada I didn't solve it in the end. Just left it as is.

Comment: I fixed it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324028/javafx-how-to-keep-the-xychart-ticks-constant/43327123#43327123